# http post for mulitpart form

Tags: apex, http, post

am trying to post the csv data through http post to end point url.

Below is my code.

```
      string test = 'test1,test1@gmail.com'; // which will be get from DB and make as CSV string


      String header = '--'+boundary+'\n';  //boundary is random string
      String footer = '\n'+boundary+'--';

      String bodyText = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload";'
                    + '\nfilename="test.csv"'
                    + '\nContent-Type: text/csv'
                    + '\n' + test;

      String body = header + bodyText + footer;
      req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
      req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(body.length()));
      req.setMethod('POST');
      req.setEndpoint(myendpoint);
      req.setBody(body);
      req.setTimeout(60000);
```

The problem is I couldn't able to post the data.

I make query from DB and make the data as CSV string.

Then put those CSV string in request body.

The requirement is I need to post the file.

Is it because the request can't be done successfully as I am making CSV string and put into request body?

Can anyone give me headstart?

I have been stuck on this problem quite long time now.

PS: I even tested whether my request header are right or not with posttestserver.com with REST client firefox plug in. Still can't post. Pls check out the test result. http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2013/07/01/01.18.49320686031

[on salesforce](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/http-post-for-mulitpart-form/td-p/642661)

Comment: The posttestserver.com text includes at least a partial answer to your problem. You didn't specify a file size, and so the server rejected the request. Note that the error code was 3. Try including a Content-Length header.

Comment: hi sdcfox, I idd include Content-Length in request header when I do both with coding and test with REST client. req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(body.length()));

Comment: Two problems here, actually. (1) footer should be '\n--'+boundary+'--' (you forgot the leading --), and (2) I'm fairly sure you need TWO \n between the mime headers and the file body, plus two between the body and the footer (e.g. a blank line should appear between each). Meaning that footer should probably be '\n\n--'+boundary+'--', and header should have +'\n\n' instead of +'\n';

Comment: My first comment was simply me mis-reading the error. You can see the error message about a file being declared but not uploaded, which suggests that the content wasn't properly delimited.

Comment: hi sfcfoc.. you saved my day. I have been stuck on this problem for so long.. :'( . could you pls answer this with your last comment. Then I will accept it as answer. Thanks you so much. Now it is working .. yahooooooooooooooo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string test = 'test1,test1@gmail.com'; // which will be get from DB and make as CSV string


  String header = '--'+boundary+'\n';  //boundary is random string
  String footer = '\n\n--'+boundary+'--'; // blank line separates body/footer

  String bodyText = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload";\n'
                + 'filename="test.csv"\n'
                + 'Content-Type: text/csv\n\n' // Blank line separates header/body
                + test;

  String body = header + bodyText + footer;
  req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
  req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(body.length()));
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setEndpoint(myendpoint);
  req.setBody(body);
  req.setTimeout(60000);
```

Comment: fwiw I had to replace **\n** with **\r\n** for my nodejs rest endpoint to parse correctly using busboy.